# What happened to the English dub of Ashita no Joe?

Tags: tomorrows-joe

I was wondering why there's an *Ashita no Joe* English dubbed commercial but no dubbed anime since there was a commercial saying it was coming to English dubbed. I'd think there was one, but there isn't.

Why is it still not available? Or if there is one, where can I find it?

Comment: I know the dub version probably stinks cause of how old it is but i've always liked watching the old animes due to the fact i grew up on old animes before I even knew they were animes from japan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the story:

On August 13, 2017, [Anime News Network announced](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2017-08-13/discotek-licenses-cyborg-009-the-cyborg-soldier-tomorrow-joe-project-arms-niea_7-lupin-iii-the-legend-of-the-gold-of-babylon/.120065) that Discotek had licensed, among other things, the 1980 film Ashita no Joe (aka Tomorrow's Joe) and would be releasing it on Blu-ray and DVD in Japanese with English subs and in English. The English dub would be from the 2008 DVD release of the film by Tai Seng.

Somewhat confusingly, the Discotek website doesn't have anything more recent than 2015. However, their FB page talks about the release being on [March 27, 2018.](https://www.facebook.com/Discotekmedia/photos/coming-march-27th-2018-tomorrow's/1954255051270246/)

This new release can be found on places like [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B079J85639) and [Blu-ray.com](http://www.blu-ray.com/movies/Tomorrows-Joe-The-Movie-Blu-ray/198537/). As for the Tai Seng version, I can't find any instances of the DVD on the internet, but I admittedly didn't search all that hard. If you're really determined to find that version ([of which the quality apparently wasn't great](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/buried-treasure/2008-11-13/ashita-no-joe?ann-edition=uk)), you can probably find it if you search hard enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm well aware of how bad the english dub is due to how old it is but for me i grew up on old animes long before I knew Japan created them and I've always had a soft spot for them no matter the quaility anyways thanks a lot for your quick reply and for the information.